# How to make one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to make a one to many relationship using eloquent model and want to show the products in the specified category 
that is my product model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use softDeletes;
    protected $table='products';

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

And that is my category model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
    use softDeletes;
    protected $table='category';

   public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product','category_id','id');
   }
}
```

And that's the product controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class productsController extends Controller
{
    public function getShow($id,Request $request){
            $in=$request->get('id');
            $category=Category::all();
            $product=Product::find($id);
            $products=$product->category()->where('category_id','=',$in);

            return view ('contents.products')->with('products',$products)
                                            ->with('category',$category);
    }
}
```

And this is the product table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('category_id');
        $table->string('describtion');
        $table->string('image_name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

And that is the category table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

And it gives me this error : Call to a member function category() on a non-object

So how can i solve it ?

Comment: can you show your db tables ??

Comment: Did you go through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) correctly ?

Comment: @user3514160 yes as u see in the question above i used it just like the documentation

Comment: Then why are you passing `where` method while you have defined it as `belongsTo` relationship ? In the docs, I don't see anywhere written as you can pass `where` method for the `belongsTo` relationship..

Comment: i use where to compare the category_id with the id passed in the url

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry I understand your point, but I want to know why are you passing `where` method to the relationship wherein your result will be a single model ? What is the purpose of using `where` method in a `belongsTo` relationship ?

Comment: i see , so u mean that it has no use in this part ?

Comment: That is the reason I asked you, Did you go through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) correctly ?

Comment: but when i removed it , it gave me this error : Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$category

Comment: and when i watched videos explaining it , they used the where clause as they needed to make a condition and that is why i used it

Comment: and when i get it back it gave me this error : Method category does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your question :

In your controller:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$products = $category->product;
```

Better yet you could use eager loading and forget about assigning products manually:

Controller:

```
$category = Category::with('product')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Hope this help you .

Comment: in this u r not getting the category_id from the url so it won't get the right one ?!!! and also will those be written in the category controller or the product ?

Comment: $id var that you passed in the method is category id right? And you want to show the product of each category when user clicks on the category right ? So, when user clicks on category you pass the category id to the product controller and get the product list accordingly .'

Comment: when i tried it it gives me the following error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: ErrorException in productsController.php line 18:
Trying to get property of non-object , that is the full error